# How to retrieve data from different tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
Time: ID, UserID, start, End
User: ID, ClientID
```

I want to retrieve all the time associated with users having client ClientID for a period.

e.g

the time associated with users having client ClientID = 5 and Time startdate >15/12/12
Table Time values

```
1, 3, 17/12/12 , 18/12/12
2, 5, 16/12/12 , 18/12/12
3, 4, 19/12/12 , 20/12/12
```

Table User values

```
1, 4
2, 3
3, 5
4, 5
```

Result should be:

```
1, 3 17/12/12 , 18/12/12
3, 4, 19/12/12 , 20/12/12
```

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Time T
    INNER JOIN User U ON T.UserId = U.Id
WHERE U.ClientId = @ClientId
```

Here's some fiddle for you: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edc4b/3

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from time t, user u
where t.id = u.id
and u.ClientID = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't what exactly you are trying to say but requirement looks fairly simple to me

```
select t.* from User u, Time t where u.id = t.userid and u.clientid= ?
```